# Unexpected static libraries

Tags: homebrew, libraries

I am having this warning when run `brew doctor`

> Warning: Unbrewed static libraries were found in /usr/local/lib. If
>   you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
>   building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

```
Unexpected static libraries:
/usr/local/lib/libFaceGen_Macosx.a
/usr/local/lib/libGranny.a
/usr/local/lib/liblibexpat.a
```

I read some posts about libraries but any with those names. I would like to know if I ingnore this or need to do something?

Thanks!

Comment: As `brew doctor` says, you can ignore these warnings if everything you use Homebrew for works fine.

Comment: Thank you! I hope everything works well.